# How do I connect my Android app to a remote MySQL database?

Tags: java, android, mysql

I'm new to android app development.

Can I connect directly to a remote MySQL database?

If not, do I need to send a `POST` or `GET` request to a URL that'll handle the database instead?

Is it dangerous to connect directly to a remote MySQL database since you'd put the username and password in your code where anyone can see it?

Comment: Usually you create a web service to interact with your APP

Comment: Try to check this post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6572282/android-connecting-to-a-remote-db-mysql

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to connect to a database remote from the application, but its not at all recommended.
Mainly because it would be very easy to sniff the traffic and possibly retrieve password and such for the server (as you guessed).
The best way (as you also mentioned) is usually to build some type of API that handles the database communication and then send requests to it from the phone.

Comment: Additional reasons why to use a web service: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15853367/jdbc-vs-web-service-for-android